# Converting types via unions doesn't work when using structs

Tags: c, struct, byte, union, bit-fields

I want to be able to "concat" bytes together, so that if I have bytes `00101` and `010` the result will be `00101010`

For this task I have written the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char bits0to5 : 6;
    unsigned char bits5to11 : 6;
    unsigned char bits11to15 : 4;
}foo;
typedef union
{
    foo bytes_in_one_form;
    long bytes_in_other_form : 16;
}bar;
int main()
{
    bar example;
    /*just in case the problem is that bytes_in_other_form wasn't initialized */
    example.bytes_in_other_form = 0;
    /*001000 = 8, 000101 = 5, 1111 = 15*/
    example.bytes_in_one_form.bits0to5 = 8;
    example.bytes_in_one_form.bits5to11 = 5;
    example.bytes_in_one_form.bits11to15 = 15;
    /*sould be 0010000001011111 = 8287*/
    /*NOTE: maybe the printf is wrong since its only 2 bytes and from type long?*/
    printf("%d", example.bytes_in_other_form); 
    /*but number printed is 1288*/
    return 0;
}
```

What have I done wrong? Unions should have all their member share the same memory, and both the `struct` and the `long` take up exactly 2 bytes.

Note:

For solutions that use entirely different algorithm, please note I need to be able to have the zeros at the start (so for example `8 = 001000` and not `1000`, and the solution should match any number of bytes at any distribution (although understanding what I did wrong in my current algorithm is better) I should also mention I use ANSI C.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does your code use the same symbol for struct name as it does for typedef name?  It is typically better to choose different symbols for each, i.e. if both are even needed.

Comment: @ryyker is my struct definition wrong? should I delete the ```typedef``` ?

Comment: No, the typedef is okay, but I do not see that the struct name is needed for this example code though.  And if it was needed, although its not illegal to use same symbols for each item, it is confusing, and in some case one can mask the other.

Comment: @ryyker have removed the names

Comment: Please don't change the question after it's answered.  My answer no longer applies to the current question, and was down-voted by someone who arrived later and didn't see the original question.

Comment: @avivgood2 - The mose recent quarrel in comments is a good example of the confusion caused by changing the core content of your original post.  It is always okay to add clarifying content, especially when asked by those trying to help, but it is essential that the core content remain the same, mistakes and all.  After all, these are the things being addressed.  If you change them, it invalidates, and confuses the train of conversation.

Comment: Normally bit numbers start at lowest significance bit (lsb). Your naming is rather confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer applies to the original question, which had:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char bits0to5 : 6;
    unsigned char bits5to11 : 6;
    unsigned char bits11to15 : 4;
}foo;
```

Here's what's happening in your specific example (note that the results may vary from one platform to another):

The bit fields are being packed into `char` variables.  If the next bit field doesn't fit into the current `char`, it skips to the next one.  Additionally, you have little-endian addressing, so the `char` values appear right-to-left in the aliased `long` bit field.

So the layout of the structure fields is:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|....cccc|..bbbbbb|..aaaaaa|
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Where `aaaaaa` is the first field, `bbbbbb` is the second field, `cccc` is the third field, and the `.` values are padding.

When storing your values, you have:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|....1111|..000101|..001000|
+--------+--------+--------+
```

With zeroes in the pad bits, this becomes:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|00001111|00000101|00001000|
+--------+--------+--------+
```

The other value in the union is aliased to the low-order 16 bits, so the value it picks up is:

```
+--------+--------+
|00000101|00001000|
+--------+--------+
```

This is `0x0508`, which in decimal is `1288` as you saw.

If the structure instead uses `unsigned long` for the bit field types, then we have:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned long bits0to5 : 6;
    unsigned long bits5to11 : 6;
    unsigned long bits11to15 : 4;
}foo;
```

In this case, the fields are packed into an `unsigned long` as follows:

```
    -----+--------+--------+
    .....|11110001|01001000|
    -----+--------+--------+
```

The low-order 16 bits are `0xf148`, which is `61768` in decimal.

Comment: So that's whats happening! How do I make the bit fields to use the same bytes?

Comment: I don't think C guarantees the packing, but if you change the `char` to a larger integer type it will most likely pack them in the same integer field.  E.g. `int` or `unsigned` or `long` or `unsigned long` etc.

Comment: cahnged them all to long now the number is too big at 61768.

Comment: No, that's exactly the correct value:  `1111`, `000101`, and `001000`, with no padding, are the 16-bit value `1111000101001000` which is `0xf148`, which is `61768` in decimal.

Comment: But this is upside down. I guess it has an easy fix of just declaring the first member last but I Am just interested why it is declared that way (upside down)

Comment: It's not upside down, it's right-to-left, which is a direct consequence of a little-endian machine architecture.  I explicitly mentioned this in my answer.  On a little-endian machine, the address of an integer is the address of the low-order byte.  if you store the value `0x12345678` in an integer, then read out the bytes in sequence, they come out as `8`, `7`, ...`1`.

Comment: you understood correctly. I want the numbers to come right after each other without overriding

Comment: Hopefully it's clear now.  Also, note that the right-to-left packing is independent of the use of bit fields.  If you have a struct of `char` values, no bit fields, and alias it with an `int` in a union, you will see that the values are packed right-to-left (on a little-endian machine).  On big-endian machines it's the opposite.

Comment: Nicely explained.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The bitfields will be packed into the unsigned long until it can hold it 6.7.2.1.10

Comment: @P__J__ No, the question was changed.  My answer applies to the original question.  I am editing it now to reflect the changes to the question.  You never saw the question that I answered.

Comment: @Tom Karzes so do you mean the code is not portable? (Becuse its machine depended) Do you know which of the two typed of architecture does ubuntu belongs to?

Comment: @TomKarzes edited the question to make some sense here

Comment: @avivgood2 It is definitely not portable.  Structure packing in general is not portable, and then bit fields are involved, it is even less so.